# How can detect an image within another image in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pattern-matching

Hi I have a color palette like this one, 
[image]

I have an image.  the image contains a color palette like this. I need to detect this color palett from the image and crop the color palette from the image. Are their any libraries in java to do that. That is  given a reference image are their any library that can use this as template and extract the image from the picture?

Here is an example, if the image is [image]

and my reference image is like the first image, I want to detect the first image within the second image and crop that portion to get the similar image image to the reference image. After cropping the second image I will get [image]

Comment: Can you give an example input image, and the expected cropped output?

Comment: are you talkning about subimaging problem? If so, maybe [this](http://werner.yellowcouch.org/Papers/subimg/index.html) theory can be helpful

Comment: @PavelK.Are there any java implementation of above example.

Comment: well, I don't know a direct implementation. Actually it depends on your goals. But if you need an implementation of FFT, you could take a look at [this](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) one.

Comment: Hi I do not know much about image processing. What should I do with the FFT?

Comment: Hi what about template matching using javacv?http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called "Template Matching". It is an image processing algorithm. Details here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching.

I am no expert in Java so am not aware of any implementation. It is a pretty simple algorithm. If this is what you are looking for you can code it your self.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a reference image already, then the below link solves your problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516753/2421703 Here, all you need to do is instead of coloring the border, create a new image file with that content