# How to check if an image is contained in another image?

Tags: java, image

I am trying to check if an image is on a program's interface. I know how to grab the program's image but I cannot figure out a way to check if the image on on the program's screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think checking containing one image in another is a question of "computer vision", so maybe some special libraries like [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) can helps you.

And this question on stackoverflow could be so useful too
[OpenCV Template Matching example in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001083/opencv-template-matching-example-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the checking within the same program as the one that loads the image, it should be possible by checking the user interface control properties/attributes, and also the return values of the functions/methods used to set the image. In such a situation, Computer Vision is overkill. In this case, may be you can post some of the code used for loading the image, so that others can suggest solutions.

But if you are using a different program to capture the screen and look for the image, SIFT and SURF features of OpenCV should do the job. The accuracy won't be bad in this application.